# What is the equivalent of Java's BigInteger(..).longValue() in Rust?

Tags: rust

In Java I can do this:

```java
new BigInteger(arrayOfBytes).longValue()
```

How can I do that same thing in Rust? That is, given an array of bytes, how can I convert it into what's in Java `longValue`?

Answer (score 0):

There is a crate for exactly that purpose (reading integers from byte slices): [byteorder](https://crates.io/crates/byteorder)

Example usage:

```
extern crate byteorder;

use std::io::Cursor;
use byteorder::{NativeEndian, ReadBytesExt};

fn main() {
    let mut array_of_bytes = Cursor::new(b"\xDE\xAD\xBE\xEF\xCA\xFE\xBA\xBE"); // input

    println!("{}", array_of_bytes.read_i64::<NativeEndian>().unwrap());
}
```

[Playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=0916bdb4bb23d83d6d39d1ff2972fffc&version=stable)

Comment: and witthout the crate?

Comment: without the crate u either need some bit level logic or unsafe memory operations such as transmute or copying. (depending on endianness)

Comment: The [Javadoc for `longValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#longValue()) indicates that the lower bits of the *arbitrary-precision number* are used. I believe that `read_i64` will panic if there are more than 8 bytes.

Comment: afaik `read_foo` in the byteorder crate just reads as many values as it needs. so if there are more than 8 bytes it will just read 8 bytes and set the cursor to the new position.

Comment: @Shepmaster "I believe that `read_i64` will panic if there are more than 8 bytes." Why do you think so? At this point the array is actually a byte stream, which implements `Read`. `read_i64` will read 8 bytes and turn them into an `i64`. This does assume that the big integer is LE-encoded, the question does not specify this anyway.

Comment: @belst Yes, I was mixing up `ByteOrder::read_i64` (panics on too many) and `ReadBytesExt::read_i64` (reads enough). However, my point about the arbitrary precision number still stands. If the input bytes were `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]` (8x `0`, 1x `1`) then the result should not be 0 (I'm not thinking through the big/little endian details, but I hope my example is clear).

Comment: @E_net4 please see my clarification above.

Comment: @Shepmaster "If the input bytes were [...] (8x 0, 1x 1) then the result should not be 0" Why not? That's exactly what `BigInteger#longValue()` would do. Yes, sudden magnitude changes can happen, including sign flips, but that's just how the method works. My main concern here still is the lack of detail in the question, though.

Comment: @belst This [example Java code](https://gist.github.com/shepmaster/2fd5ae0bd64f7ce556ebc977ed1d6f37) prints out 1. The code presented will always print `1`. I'm told that Java is always Big Endian, so using `NativeEndian` doesn't seem right; plus the non-use of all the bytes.

Comment: @Shepmaster "Java is always big endian" might be a bit of an overstatement, but the `BigInteger` constructor definitely [interprets the given array as big-endian](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(byte[])). So the answer is technically wrong, although it is far from clear whether the OP wanted an *exact* equivalent of the Java snippet, or something that produces the same result in some reasonable subset of cases.

Comment: @user4815162342 that's why I qualified it with "I'm told that" — I didn't do any verification of the truth of the statement myself ^_^.

Comment: @Shepmaster Interestingly, the `num_bigint` crate doesn't appear to offer a `BigInt` constructor equivalent to Java's `BigInteger(byte[])`, which interprets the provided byte array as a two's-complement binary representation of the number. With `num_bigint::BigInt`, `from_bytes_be` and `from_bytes_le` convert from a sign+magnitude representation.

Comment: @user4815162342 I made a pull request to address that issue. https://github.com/rust-num/num/pull/304

Comment: @E_net4 Nice! I have to wonder, though, if there is an actual use case for such conversion, besides "java BigInt implements them"? The OP immediately discards anything other than the lowest four bytes by converting the number to `long`.

Comment: @user4815162342 Admittedly, `bigint` is not very useful in this context. Still, it doesn't sound too farfetched to prefer having a single array in two's complement instead of an array and a sign value when saving the number. I'll leave the judgement of value to the owners of `num`. :)